# De onde vem 'se pá'?

Tags: etimologia, expressões, gíria

Tipicamente nos estados brasileiros de São Paulo e Rio de Janeiro (principalmente o primeiro), em registro inculto e informal, usa-se a [gíria](http://www.qualeagiria.com.br/giria/se-pa/) '*[se pá](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/se%20p%C3%A1/)*' como [sinônimo](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/se_p%C3%A1) perfeito de '*talvez*', embora sem uso de subjuntivo para o verbo subsequente.

De acordo com o [Wiktionary](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/se_p%C3%A1), *se pá* significa primariamente *quiçá*, consequentemente *talvez*, *possivelmente*, *quem sabe*.

> Se pá ele **vai** à festa. Talvez ele **vá** à festa.

Após considerável pesquisa, não encontrei o que desejava. **Qual é a origem da expressão '*se pá*'?**

Especulo que o '*se*' seja simplesmente a conjunção condicional, porém, o que é '*pá*'? Será onomatopeia para impacto, como se *pá*, se algo acontecer (pois todo evento possui uma consequência e, portanto, — figurativamente — impacto)? Ou apenas uma corruptela ou abreviação, cuja proveniência não concebo?

Comment: O *pá* como interjeição de impacto é bastante estabelecido (e.g., [aqui](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/p%C3%A1)), então sempre interpretei a expressão "se pá" como sinônimo de "se rolar/funcionar/bater/encaixar/etc.". O "pá" em Portugal é também um encurtamento, talvez de rapaz, que equivale ao "cara" no Brasil: "ó pá, vens ou não?", "ô cara, vem ou não?", mas não me parece que esse seja o sentido que aparece na expressão "se pá".

Comment: O uso deve ser restrito a grupos mais jovens.  Nunca ouvi por aqui (Rio de Janeiro).

Comment: Nossa, nunca ouviu Centaurus? Já ouvi gente de 60 70 anos dizendo...
Acho que disse bem o Stafusa... Me parece que o "pá" teria o sentido de paulada, quase uma interjeição sonora, tipo "pá" (a paulada acontecer), portanto como ele disse, "se rolar", ou "quem sabe", ou "é possível"

Comment: Como usuário dessa gíria na juventude, posso dizer que interpretava "pá" como uma onomatopeia para um evento súbito, repentino. Em relação ao significado, entendia "se pá" também como sinônimo da expressão "se der".

Comment: Sei lá rapaz.....eu gostaria de saber quando surgiu esse se pá.

Comment: @Lambie Eu também. Dei uma olhada novamente, e achei indicações de que teria sido nos anos 2000: 1) [dicionário informal](https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/se%20p%C3%A1/) "Significado de Se pá Por Verônica (SP) em 20-07-2007: Talvez"; 2) [O Globo (2012)](https://oglobo.globo.com/rio/as-novas-girias-que-prometem-pegar-de-vez-os-cariocas-durante-verao-6875429) "Importada de São Paulo, “se pá” quer dizer “talvez” e já circula nas agências de publicidade cariocas".

Comment: Não sei dizer se espero uma ligação entre o "pá" de "se pá" e o "pá" do bordão do personagem humorístico [Patropi](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escolinha_do_Barulho#Perfil_dos_alunos), "um pá daqui, pá dali, pá de lá e pá de cá".

Comment: Olá! Sobre a influencia de francês no linguajar das elites brasileiras, li certa vez em um livro sobre São Paulo antiga de uma moda de contratar babás e professoras (de piano, de artes) francesas para as crianças de famílias abastadas. Por isso a classe média paulistana absorveu palavras francesas no vocabulário por puro esnobismo, pra dizer que conseguia pagar por esse luxo. Vou procurar a referência e voltar aqui. =)

Answer (score 1):

Olha, tudo que eu vou dizer aqui é baseado nos meus quase 30 anos vivendo em São Paulo e falando o "dialeto paulistano", não creio que hajam registros disto, então o máximo que você vai conseguir são relatos tipo o meu. Pá aqui em SP (onde acredito que a expressão se originou) é uma espécie de "gíria coringa", a usamos para tudo.

"Ai ele foi lá e pá" = ele foi lá e fez
"Eu estou meio pá hoje" = não estou muito bem hoje
"Então você é o pá?" = então você é o bom?

Dito isto, o "se pá" entra nesse mesmo balaio, se pá é uma espécie de "se algo" por isso serve como talvez.

Mas de novo, isso é tudo baseado na minha experiência pessoal, se houverem aqui links para artigos mais bem embasados por favor me enviem pois adoraria lê-los

Comment: Bem-vindo Fabricio. Obrigado pela contribuição e por compreender a importância das fontes. Entendo que você nos dá um relato, mas o que na sua experiência te faz acreditar que a expressão se originou em São Paulo?

Comment: olá @stafusa, o termo "se pá" é intimamente ligado a comunidade do rap no Brasil, e o grande centro do RAP nacional é São Paulo, procurei exaustivamente por registros, artigos ou pesquisas relacionadas a este termo, mas não encontrei nada a não ser achismos. Peço perdão pela falta de fontes mas neste tema específico elas são muito escassas, pra não dizer inexistentes

Comment: Obrigado Fabricio!

Comment: Outro exemplo, mais antigo, é o "pá" do bordão do personagem humorístico [Patropi](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escolinha_do_Barulho#Perfil_dos_alunos), criado no [fim dos anos 1980](http://g1.globo.com/sp/bauru-marilia/noticia/2016/10/acervo-dos-personagens-de-orival-pessini-e-incinerado-ele-era-unico.html): "um pá daqui, pá dali, pá de lá e pá de cá".

Answer (score -1):

E simplesmente uma gíria no lugar de uma palavra coloca pá.
Exemplo: poxa mano eu tava ali e pá a nega mim deu altas idéias
Como deveria ser: poxa mano eu tava ali e a nega mim deu altas idéias.
Ex: Rapaz o carrro bateu pá e o cara saiu sem prestar socorro.
Como deveria: Rapaz o carro bateu e o cara saiu sem prestar socorro.
E uma gíria que as pessoas usam para acrescentar à frase.
Esse pá é daqui do Brasil mesmo uma gíria nossa.

Comment: Francie, bem-vindo ao site. Obrigado pela contribuição. Neste site tentamos usar referências porque uma resposta a essa pergunta sem referências, como a tua, é equivalente à “pá é ‘ser’ em Guatuliano, portanto, ‘se pá' é ‘se for’”. Obrigado pela contribuição de qualquer jeito.

Answer (score -1):

"se der par" (???)

O "pá" como onomatopeia faz todo o sentido pra mim, mas antes de ler os comentários eu tava pensando que poderia ser uma abreviação para " se der par". ><

Comment: Rik, bem-vindo ao site. Nós aqui pretendemos respostas fundamentadas. Tu basicamente limitas-te a comentar os que os outros já disseram.

Answer (score -1):

Sei que faz muito tempo já esse pergunta, mas queria dar minha contribuição.

Dia desses estava assistindo um filme francês, cujo título em inglês é Close (filme de 2022). Nele, um rapazinho fala algo que soa como "se pá", e foi legendado como "talvez". Dando uma pesquisada, descobri que o que o menino disse foi "sais pas", que significa "se o acaso permitir", "se rolar". Engraçado que tem a denotação de "se pá".

Pra mim faz bastante sentido vc fazer (se já não ou fez) sua pesquisa nessa linha, mas não sei se de fato existe ligação.

Comment: "sais pas" en francês, não significa "se o acaso permitir" en francês mas "não sei"

Answer (score -3):

Possivelmente do francês, "Je sais pas" (não sei), ordinariamente falado e pronunciado com "je" mudo: "s' pa!". Dito quando não se possui a certeza sobre algo, daí a transferência de significado do "não sei" para "talvez".

Comment: Não conheço o francês como uma língua ou comunidade influente no Brasil. Talvez explicando isso, esta resposta ficasse mais sólida; como está, parece-me fracamente fundamentada.

Comment: Isso é mera etimologia especulativa.

Answer (score -3):

Como já dito, também acredito vir do francês, "je ne sais pas", "eu não sei". Os falantes franceses juntam tudo e falam algo como "j'pa", que pode facilmente ter virado "se pá". Essa mega contração de "je ne sais pas" é bem comum, pode ser facilmente encontrada em músicas não-clássicas, filmes e etc.

Comment: João, bem-vindo ao site! Para fortaleceres o teu argumento, deves referenciar no teu texto; sem referência, o teu texto é pura especulação. Para dar-te um exemplo: eu poderia falar que “mano” vem do inglês “man”, já que ambos são sinónimos e parecidos, mas “mano” não vem de “man”, eu estaria errado. Capisci?

Answer (score -3):

Sim, nos possuímos algumas influencias do francês como citado por alguns outros comentários, isso se vê mais nas capitais São Paulo, Belo Horizonte e Rio, vejo muito em BH, tanto que lá usamos o r muito mais puxado do que em outras regiões do Brasil, uma clara influência francesa por conta de serem muito influentes no séculos 17 e 18, nessa época falar com o sotaque forçado com o r era "chique"

Comment: Alex, bem-vindo ao site! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas aqui se tenta usar referências para fortalecer as respostas. Se a resposta estiver sem nenhuma referência, ela se equivale em força a esta: «“Se pá” vem do alemão antigo “süpa”, que significava o mesmo.». Obrigado pela contribuição ainda assim.